# Time complexity of zadd in redis

Tags: redis, time-complexity, sortedset

I have read that insertion time complexity of skip lists is order of (log n) with very high probability but O(n) in worst case. But while reading the documentation of redis zadd at https://redis.io/commands/zadd It tells that: O(log(N)) for each item added, where N is the number of elements in the sorted set.

If redis uses skip lists, then zadd should be O(n) in worst case, isn't it ?

ps: Sorry, but I posted the same question earlier but didn't get any response.
Deleted that and creating again.

Answer (score 0):

Redis' implementation of `skiplist` is a modification of *William Pugh*'s paper. So, in worst case, the time complexity is `O(n)`. The **AVERAGE** time complexity of `ZADD` is `O(log(n))`.